# How to open the device setting on home button click - android

Tags: android, setting, home-button

want to open the setting of the device when i click on the home button in the device i tried this code but when the app start its open the device setting automatically

```
        @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
       super.onAttachedToWindow();
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD); 
       startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
    }
```

how to make this code open the setting of the device when the home key button clicked only ?

Comment: You shouldn't (and can't, really) override a device's Home button. Why not just provide a Button to open the Settings?

Comment: i try to do something new in my app but i cant find it until now (the home key ) .. do you know the home key code ? i tried this on the return key and works --->  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
  
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
  }
  return false;
 }  ---- but i want to control on the home key button not the return back key

Comment: Your users will not be happy if you override the default Home button on their devices. I would go with Mike's suggestion above if I were you.

Comment: yes but the app including new idea and this movement will make the app looks new as the idea